# c# Thread Contention with SqlDataReaders and SqlDataAdapters

Tags: multithreading, scaling, sqldatareader

We notice that inside of our .Net application we have contention when it comes to using SqlDataReader. While we understand that SqlDataReader is not ThreadSafe, it should scale. The following code is a simple example to show that we cannot scale our application because there is contention on the SqlDataReader GetValue method. We are not bound by CPU, Disk, or Network; Just the internal contention on the SqlDataReader. We can run the application 10 times with 1 thread and it scales linearly, but 10 threads in 1 app does not scale. Any thoughts on how to scale reading from SQL Server in a single c# application?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ThreadAndSQLTester
{
    class Host
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the receive workers.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The receive workers.</value>
        internal List<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the receive threads.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The receive threads.</value>
        internal List<Thread> Threads { get; set; }

        public int NumberOfThreads { get; set; }
        public int Sleep { get; set; }
        public int MinutesToRun { get; set; }
        public bool IsRunning { get; set; }
        private System.Timers.Timer runTime;

        private object lockVar = new object();

        public Host()
        {
            Init(1, 0, 0);
        }

        public Host(int numberOfThreads, int sleep, int minutesToRun)
        {
            Init(numberOfThreads, sleep, minutesToRun);
        }

        private void Init(int numberOfThreads, int sleep, int minutesToRun)
        {
            this.Workers = new List<Worker>();
            this.Threads = new List<Thread>();

            this.NumberOfThreads = numberOfThreads;
            this.Sleep = sleep;
            this.MinutesToRun = minutesToRun;

            SetUpTimer();
        }

        private void SetUpTimer()
        {
            if (this.MinutesToRun > 0)
            {
                this.runTime = new System.Timers.Timer();
                this.runTime.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(this.MinutesToRun).TotalMilliseconds;
                this.runTime.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(runTime_Elapsed);
                this.runTime.Start();
            }
        }

        void runTime_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.runTime.Stop();
            this.Stop();
            this.IsRunning = false;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            this.IsRunning = true;

            Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

            for (int i = 0; i < this.NumberOfThreads; i++)
            {
                string threadPoolId = Math.Ceiling(r.NextDouble() * 10).ToString();

                Worker worker = new Worker("-" + threadPoolId); //i.ToString());
                worker.Sleep = this.Sleep;

                this.Workers.Add(worker);

                Thread thread = new Thread(worker.Work);
                worker.Name = string.Format("WorkerThread-{0}", i);

                thread.Name = worker.Name;

                this.Threads.Add(thread);
                thread.Start();

                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Started new Worker Thread. Total active: {0}", i + 1));
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (this.Workers != null)
            {
                lock (lockVar)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.Workers.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //Thread thread = this.Threads[i];
                        //thread.Interrupt();
                        this.Workers[i].IsEnabled = false;
                    }

                    for (int i = this.Workers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        Worker worker = this.Workers[i];
                        while (worker.IsRunning)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(32);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (Thread thread in this.Threads)
                    {
                        thread.Abort();
                    }

                    this.Workers.Clear();
                    this.Threads.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ThreadAndSQLTester
{
    class Worker
    {
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
        public bool IsRunning { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Sleep { get; set; }

        private string dataCnString { get; set; }
        private string logCnString { get; set; }

        private List<Log> Logs { get; set; }

        public Worker(string threadPoolId)
        {
            this.Logs = new List<Log>();

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder cnBldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            cnBldr.DataSource = @"trgcrmqa3";
            cnBldr.InitialCatalog = "Scratch";
            cnBldr.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            cnBldr.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
            cnBldr.Pooling = true;            

            dataCnString = GetConnectionStringWithWorkStationId(cnBldr.ToString(), threadPoolId);            

            cnBldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            cnBldr.DataSource = @"trgcrmqa3";
            cnBldr.InitialCatalog = "Scratch";
            cnBldr.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            logCnString = GetConnectionStringWithWorkStationId(cnBldr.ToString(), string.Empty);

            IsEnabled = true;
        }

        private string machineName { get; set; }
        private string GetConnectionStringWithWorkStationId(string connectionString, string connectionPoolToken)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(machineName)) machineName = Environment.MachineName;

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder cnbdlr;
            try
            {
                cnbdlr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("connection string was an invalid format");
            }

            cnbdlr.WorkstationID = machineName + connectionPoolToken;

            return cnbdlr.ConnectionString;
        }

        public void Work()
        {
            int i = 0;

            while (this.IsEnabled)
            {
                this.IsRunning = true;

                try
                {
                    Log log = new Log();
                    log.WorkItemId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    log.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
                    List<object> lst = new List<object>();

                    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(this.dataCnString))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            cn.Open();

                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Analysis.spSelectTestData", cn))
                            {
                                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)) // DBHelper.ExecuteReader(cn, cmd))
                                {                                    
                                    while (dr.Read())
                                    {
                                        CreateClaimHeader2(dr, lst);
                                    }

                                    dr.Close();
                                }

                                cmd.Cancel();
                            }
                        }
                        catch { }
                        finally
                        {
                            cn.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    log.StopTime = DateTime.Now;
                    log.RouteName = this.Name;
                    log.HostName = this.machineName;

                    this.Logs.Add(log);
                    i++;

                    if (i > 1000)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread: {0} executed {1} items.", this.Name, i));
                        i = 0;
                    }

                    if (this.Sleep > 0) Thread.Sleep(this.Sleep);
                }
                catch { }
            }

            this.LogMessages();

            this.IsRunning = false;
        }       

        private void CreateClaimHeader2(IDataReader reader, List<object> lst)
        {
            lst.Add(reader["ClaimHeaderID"]);
            lst.Add(reader["ClientCode"]);
            lst.Add(reader["MemberID"]);
            lst.Add(reader["ProviderID"]);
            lst.Add(reader["ClaimNumber"]);
            lst.Add(reader["PatientAcctNumber"]);
            lst.Add(reader["Source"]);
            lst.Add(reader["SourceID"]);
            lst.Add(reader["TotalPayAmount"]);
            lst.Add(reader["TotalBillAmount"]);
            lst.Add(reader["FirstDateOfService"]);
            lst.Add(reader["LastDateOfService"]);
            lst.Add(reader["MaxStartDateOfService"]);
            lst.Add(reader["MaxValidStartDateOfService"]);
            lst.Add(reader["LastUpdated"]);
            lst.Add(reader["UpdatedBy"]);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Toes the data table.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="data">The data.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

            if (props == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Table properties.");
            if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
            }
            object[] values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                }
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }


        private void LogMessages()
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(this.logCnString))
            {
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    DataTable dt = ToDataTable(this.Logs);

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Logging {0} records for Thread: {1}", this.Logs.Count, this.Name));

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Analysis.spInsertWorkItemRouteLog", cn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Logged {0} records for Thread: {1}", this.Logs.Count, this.Name));
                }
                finally
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. When you say there's "contention on SqlDataReader GetValue", do you mean there's lock contention? Or do you mean GetValue is taking the longest amount of time in your performance measurements?

Comment: Ok. Why are we acquiring a lock in order to use a SqlDataReader? Why not just one reader per thread?

Comment: We are using 1 reader per thread and are not acquiring a lock. Please look through the code in the post. The problem is that it seems that inside of the SqlClient assembly it appears to be using a shared resource at some point and multiple threads do not scale.

Comment: At this point, since your example is a bit complex, and you haven't received any answers, try simplifying your code to the simplest, smallest amount of code that still reproduces the problem. Narrow it down from there.

Comment: The answer can be found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/af589b9e-9794-49ca-abbc-efca2a5f19b3

Answer (score 0):

```
1.A DataReader works in a connected environment,
whereas DataSet works in a disconnected environment.

2.A DataSet represents an in-memory cache of data consisting of any number of inter related  DataTable objects. A DataTable object represents a tabular block of in-memory data.
```

[SqlDataAdapter or sqlDataReader](http://deepakgoelblog.blogspot.de/2012/06/difference-between-sqldataadapter-or.html)

Answer (score -1):

Difference between SqlDataAdapter or sqlDataReader ?
Ans  :      1.A DataReader works in a connected environment,
               whereas DataSet works in a disconnected environment.
               2.A DataSet represents an in-memory cache of data consisting of any number of inter related            DataTable objects. A DataTable object represents a tabular block of in-memory data.

[SqlDataAdapter or sqlDataReader](http://deepakgoelblog.blogspot.de/2012/06/difference-between-sqldataadapter-or.html)